# How can I include a query string with get_permalink

Tags: permalinks, redirect, login, query-string

My login link uses `wp_login_url( get_permalink() )`  so that the user is redirected back to the page they were viewing, and not to the dashboard.

However, this does not include query strings.  So if a user was at `here.com/?page=4` they would not be redirected back to page 4.

How can I include the query string in my code?

```
$items .= "<li class='menu-item'> <a href=\"".wp_login_url( get_permalink() )."\">Login</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [add_query_arg()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) to add any query parameters you want to a URI, e.g.,

```
$redirect_uri = add_query_arg ('page', '4', get_permalink ()) ;
$login_uri = wp_login_url ($redirect_uri) ;
```

Or, you could simply use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which will already contain any query string present in the current page's URI, e.g.,

```
$login_uri = wp_login_url ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm a bit confused by that function, and the explanation on its page.  It looks like I need to define every possible value.  What if there were a random ID, in which I didn't know what the value was?

`$redirect_uri = add_query_arg ('random_id', '472938742', get_permalink ()) ;`

Is there an operator that would allow any value?  Or actually, any sanitized value for security?

Comment: That's why I'd suggest just passing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to `wp_login_url()` (see [PHP: Server and execution environment information](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)).  For example, if the user were currently viewing `here.com/?page=4`, that's where they'd go back to after logging it.  If they were viewing `here.com/?page=4&random_id=472938742`, then that's where they'd go back to.