# add query string to all pages after user logged in

Tags: plugins, functions, filters, hooks, actions

I need to add query string to all pages including homepage.after user logged in.
as example
after user logged in homepage url need to look like
domain.com?aff=1234567
and other links also modify with custom query string
such as page
 domain.com?p=1&aff=1234567

anyone has idea how to do this or how  can i use wp_redirect for this

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to do? Might be an easier way.

Comment: I need to add custom variable to address bar like Original URL:http://server/?id=10    Resulting URL: http://server/?id=10&enabled=true

Comment: @srinathmadusanka I agree with Jacob, it's clear what you're trying to do, but it's not clear why? What problem does this solve? Is there a reason you can't store this info in cookies or user meta?

Comment: To do what though? What are you using the query arguments for? Do they need to be in the URL? Why not store values with user and retrieve with get_user_meta(), or store in a session variable? Why do they have to be in the URL.

Comment: it need to save to  contactform 7 via get

Answer (score -2):

add following code to functions.php,

```
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');
function your_function(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $genre_url = add_query_arg('aff', '1234567', get_permalink());
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help you.
for more information,

- [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)
- [How can I include a query string with get_permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257682/how-can-i-include-a-query-string-with-get-permalink)
- [wp_head action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)
- [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

Comment: This isn't going to do anything. It's just setting the value of `$genre_url` to the permalink of the current post with a query arg, but the variable isn't used anywhere, and certainly isn't being added to the url. Also, get_permalink() will only be correct for single posts/pages. Category and date archives won't work because get_permalink doesn't get their URLs. you'd just get the URL to the first post in the archive.